# is this formula semantically entailed from the empty set of premises?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I did the truth table of the below logic:

((p ∨ q) → r) → ((p → r) ∨ (q → r))

[image]

However I didn't quite understand what semantically entailed form the empty set of premises? What that mean exactly?

As far as i understand, Whatever P I pick, the conclusion should always be true. So in this case, is it semantically entailed form the empty set of premises?

I think it is not because

((p ∨ q) → r) <> p

in case p is T q is T and r is false

Comment: I don't understand why you think not. The formula you consider at the end doesn't look like the one that your question is about, I don't know what you mean by <>, and don't see how you are arriving from what's written to the conclusion "not semantically entailed".

Comment: <> means not equal. So is it semantically entailed from the empty set of premises?

Comment: I still don't understand why you consider that inequation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this setting, semantic entailment $S \models Q$ simply means that if you write down the truth table and throw away the rows where any of the statements in S are false (i.e. you keep only the rows where every statement in $S$ is true), then $Q$ is identically true in the remaining rows.

Thus, your truth table does indeed prove

$$ \models ((p \vee q) \to r) \to ((p \to r) \vee (q \to r)) $$

Comment: ok i understand it is semantically entailed. But what is the empty set of premises?

Comment: The empty set of premises is the empty set: the set that doesn't have any premises in it.

Answer (score -1):

> However I didn't quite understand what semantically entailed form the empty set of premises? What that mean exactly?

Is it entailed by only the rules of inference? That is: is it a tautology?

$$\models((p\lor q)\to r)\to((p\to r)\lor (q\to r))$$

Comment: You're confusing semantic entailment with syntactic entailment.

Comment: Should i look at the final result of the complete formula? In this case yes it is a tautology right?